# Lost motivation upon leaving

Tags: ethics, resignation, notice-period, politics

About to leave, and have now lost motivation to go above and beyond at my current firm, rather just focusing on my core duties and that's it.

One of the main reasons why I have decided to leave is due to office politics impacting my ability to grow within the organization. In the past I would deal with it as part of my management role by going above and beyond, but now do not feel motivated to from no longer seeing a long term future here.

Guess the question I have, now that I am about to leave, is it worth making an extra effort given it will no longer be my problem once I am gone?

Answer (score 6):

You are still an employee at your current company so you should continue to act in a professional manner.  Continue to work on your assigned tasks to the best of your ability.  There is no need to go "above and beyond", simply do what is required of you. 
 Once your notice period is over, you will not have to worry about this company anymore.

Comment: All true, but don't forget whether you're employed by this or another company, your primary duty and responsibility is to your immediate family and yourself. Any employer is a distant 2nd (or nth).

Answer (score 2):

> now that I am about to leave, is it worth making an extra effort given
>   it will no longer be my problem once I am gone?

What does that even mean? Rescuing your co-workers if the building catches on fire?

What does going above and beyond mean within the context of your job and your role at the company?

Do your job. If you're asked to pitch in on something that falls outside of the scope of your job, pitch in. You're still going to be paid, regardless of what duties and tasks you perform, whether they're "above and beyond" or not.

If you're asked to sacrifice your personal time or well being then you'll have to decide whether or not that's something you want to do.

Within the context of your job and working hours, what does it matter what you work on?

Answer (score 0):

While I will not discourage you from trying - I'll also add: Check what is the return on your extra investment of effort. Whatever effort you'll try to put forward now - mostly they will not receive their appreciation.

Given the fact that you've said:

> *One of the main reasons why I have decided to leave is due to office politics impacting my ability to grow within the organization*

It's less likely that you'll receive an acknowledgement of your extra efforts during the notice period.

Perform what is expected of you, serve the notice period and leave. All the best for the new journey.